# ¿Cómo limitar número de dígitos en el display de una calculadora en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que sucede es que tengo que realizar una calculadora con código Js la estructura en HTML y CSS ya esta lista, pero sucede que tengo que limitar el ingreso de números en el display a 8 dígitos, el proceso para las teclas ya esta listo, pero al accionar una operación como una multiplicación, el resultado excede esa cantidad. Necesito arreglarlo.
Agradezco mucho la colaboración.

```js
     var operaciona = 0;
     var operacionb = 0;
     var operacion = "";
     var resultado = 0;
     var isSign = false;




      var display = document.getElementById('display')
      display.innerHTML = '0';



    var resultado = document.getElementById('sign');
    var reset = document.getElementById('on');
    var suma = document.getElementById('mas');
    var resta = document.getElementById('menos');
    var multiplicacion = document.getElementById('por');
    var division = document.getElementById('dividido');
    var igual = document.getElementById('igual');
    var punto = document.getElementById('punto');
    var uno = document.getElementById('1');
    var dos = document.getElementById('2');
    var tres = document.getElementById('3');
    var cuatro = document.getElementById('4');
    var cinco = document.getElementById('5');
    var seis = document.getElementById('6');
    var siete = document.getElementById('7');
    var ocho = document.getElementById('8');
    var nueve = document.getElementById('9');
    var cero = document.getElementById('0');



    uno.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "1"
      }

    }


    dos.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "2"
      }
    }
    tres.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "3"
      }
    }
    cuatro.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "4"
      }
    }
    cinco.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "5"
      }
    }
    seis.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "6"
      }
    }
    siete.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "7"
      }
    }
    ocho.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "8"
      }
    }
    nueve.onclick = function(){
      if(display.innerHTML == "0"){
        display.innerHTML = "";
      }
      if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
      }else{
      display.innerHTML += "9"
      }
    }
    cero.onclick = function(){
      display.innerHTML += "0"
    }

    suma.onclick = function(){
      operaciona = display.innerHTML;
      operacion = "+";
      display.innerHTML = "";
    }

    resta.onclick = function(){
      operaciona = display.innerHTML;
      operacion = "-";
      display.innerHTML = "";
    }

    multiplicacion.onclick = function(){
      operaciona = display.innerHTML;
      operacion = "*";
      display.innerHTML = "";
    }

    division.onclick = function(){
      operaciona = display.innerHTML;
      operacion = "/";
      display.innerHTML = "";

    }
    igual.onclick = function(){
        operacionb = display.innerHTML;
        if(operacion == "+"){
        resultado = parseFloat(operaciona) + parseFloat(operacionb);
        }
        if(operacion == "-"){
        resultado = parseFloat(operaciona) - parseFloat(operacionb);
        }
        if(operacion == "*"){
        resultado = parseFloat(operaciona) * parseFloat(operacionb);
        }
        if(operacion == "/"){
        resultado = parseFloat(operaciona) / parseFloat(operacionb);
        }
        if(display.innerHTML.length >= 8){
          resultado 
        }else{
        display.innerHTML = resultado
        }



    }
    on.onclick = function(){
      display.innerHTML = "0"
    }
    sign.onclick = function(){
      isSign = !isSign;
      if(isSign && display.innerHTML!="0"){
        display.innerHTML = "-" + display.innerHTML;
      }else{
        display.innerHTML =
        display.innerHTML.slice(1);
      }
    }
    sign.onclick = function(){
      display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML + ".";
      if(display.innerHTML!="0"){
        display.innerHTML =  display.innerHTML + "." ;
      }else{
        display.innerHTML =
        display.innerHTML.slice(1);
      }
    }
    uno.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
          uno.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
      })
      uno.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
          uno.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
      })
      dos.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            dos.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        dos.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            dos.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        tres.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            tres.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        tres.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            tres.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        cuatro.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            cuatro.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        cuatro.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            cuatro.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        cinco.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            cinco.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        cinco.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            cinco.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        seis.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            seis.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        seis.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            seis.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        siete.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            siete.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        siete.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            siete.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        ocho.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            ocho.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        ocho.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            ocho.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        nueve.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            nueve.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        nueve.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            nueve.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        cero.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            cero.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        cero.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            cero.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        sign.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            sign.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        sign.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            sign.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        raiz.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            raiz.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        raiz.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            raiz.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        dividido.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            dividido.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        dividido.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            dividido.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        por.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            por.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        por.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            por.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        punto.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            punto.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        punto.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            punto.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        menos.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            menos.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        menos.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            menos.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        igual.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            igual.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        igual.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            igual.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        mas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            mas.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        mas.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            mas.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
        on.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
            on.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(0.85,0.85)")
        })
        on.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
            on.setAttribute("style","transform:scale(1,1)")
        })
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" 
     rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy" 
     rel="stylesheet">
     <title>Calculadora</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="fondo">
    <div class="titulo-container">
      <h1>¡No pierdas <span>la cuenta!</span></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="notas-container">
      <h2>Tus apuntes...</h2>
      <textarea class="nota-input" placeholder="Escribe aquí..."></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="calculadoraFondo">
      <div class="pantalla">
        <span id="display">0</span>
      </div>

      <div class="teclado">
        <img src="image/ON.png" alt="On" class="tecla" id="on"/>
        <img src="image/sign.png" alt="signo" class="tecla" id="sign"/>
        <img src="image/raiz.png" alt="raiz" class="tecla" id="raiz"/>
        <img src="image/dividido.png" alt="dividido" class="tecla divide" id="dividido"/>

        <img src="image/7.png" alt="7" class="tecla" id="7"/>
        <img src="image/8.png" alt="8" class="tecla" id="8"/>
        <img src="image/9.png" alt="9" class="tecla" id="9"/>
        <img src="image/por.png" alt="por" class="tecla multiplica" 
          id="por"/>

        <img src="image/4.png" alt="4" class="tecla" id="4"/>
        <img src="image/5.png" alt="5" class="tecla" id="5"/>
        <img src="image/6.png" alt="6" class="tecla" id="6"/>
        <img src="image/menos.png" alt="menos" class="tecla resta" 
          id="menos"/>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col1">
            <img src="image/1.png" alt="1" class="tecla" id="1"/>
            <img src="image/2.png" alt="2" class="tecla" id="2"/>
            <img src="image/3.png" alt="3" class="tecla" id="3"/>

            <img src="image/0.png" alt="0" class="tecla" id="0"/>
            <img src="image/punto.png" alt="punto" class="tecla" id="punto"/>
            <img src="image/igual.png" alt="igual" class="tecla" id="igual"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <img src="image/mas.png" alt="mas" class="tecla suma" id="mas"/>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container-libreta">
      <div class="libreta">
        <div class="contenido-ingresos">
          <h3>Ingresos</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Salario: </span>$1300.00</li>
            <li><span>Bonificación: </span>$200.00</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contenido-egresos">
          <h3>Egresos</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Renta: </span>$300.00</li>
            <li><span>Alimentos: </span>$250.00</li>
            <li><span>Restaurantes: </span>$120.00</li>
            <li><span>Automóvil: </span>$100.00</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


     </div>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una if para saber si el número va a exceder 99999999 o va a ser menor de 0.0000001 y en tal caso, lo expresas en forma exponencial con solo 2 decimales,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the exponential notation of a specified number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var num = 907098708970987099;
    var n = num.toExponential(2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

En este ejemplo, se pasa un número mucho mayor a forma exponencial usando un total de 8 dígitos: uno para el entero, otro para el punto decimal, 2 para 2 decimales y luego e+ para el exponente y dos dígitos para el  exponente.

Comment: Buenas Iker, ya que utilizaste una pagina con documentacion, y pegaste  su ejemplo, seria bueno que lo referenciaras: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toexponential.asp